# Writing a list of Java Objects into a JSON file

Tags: java, json

I am trying to write a list of Java Objects into a JSON file with the below code..

```
    JsonBO jsonBo = new JsonBO();
    jsonBo.setCDataSet(SampleBOList);
    JsonConfig jsonConfig = new JsonConfig();
    JSON json = JSONSerializer.toJSON(jsonBo, jsonConfig); 

    try {
         File file = new File("test.json");
         FileUtils.writeStringToFile(file, json.toString(), "UTF-8");
    } 

    catch (final IOException exp) 
     {
        System.out.println("Unable to write the JSON file in the given path..");
        exp.printStackTrace();
     }
```

I am able to write the normal objects in the file but not list of array objects.

Comment: "List of array objects" - where do you try to write that?

Comment: Tell us what you expect the code to do, and what it does instead. "I'm not able to" is not a clear description of the problem you have.

Comment: @mishik: I mean, i am trying to write list of BUSINESS OBJECTS(BOs) in a JSON file.
I have tried with JSON Serializer and JSON array. 

The no of objects is getting detected. 

But the values inside the objects is not getting detected and so it is not getting displayed in the output JSON file.

Comment: @JB Nizet : I am trying to write list of BUSINESS OBJECTS(BOs) in a JSON file.
I have tried with JSON Serializer and JSON array. 

The no of objects is getting detected. 

But the values inside the objects is not getting detected and so it is not getting displayed in the output JSON file.